Implementing User Activity Tracking in a MERN Stack CRM
I'm building a CRM for a small company, and I need to track all changes made by users across various documents (e.g., properties, enquiries, etc.). For example, when accessing a property, I want to see what changes were made, by whom, and when. Additionally, when viewing an account, I need to see all activities related to that account.
What’s the best way to accomplish this? Are there any plugins or open-source projects with this functionality already implemented?
So far I was looking for some docs.
